# Controlling layout and label width of a list view control in win32 ListView Icons view

Tags: listview, winapi

I am creating a win32 `ListView` in `LVS_ICON` viewing mode. I want to show the label text in just 1 line, and in case the label text crosses a certain width (which is fixed) the label text should be truncated with ellipses.

I tried setting the `ListView` Window Style property `LVS_NOLABELWRAP`, but it didn't help. It shows the full label text in a single line which looks ugly if there are big file names.

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily, the control is hard-coded to two lines of text. You could use customdraw and render it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for responding quickly. Is it possible to control the width of Label rect using custom draw? I could not figure out a way to do this using custom draw also?

Comment: You can't change the width the control thinks it's using but you can change what's drawn inside that area.